# phpword composer install to another directory

Tags: json, composer-php, phpword

I want to install phpword to another directory than its default direcroty, I already tried this in composer.json:

```
{
"name" : "phpoffice/phpword",
  "version" : "v0.13.0",
  "require": {
    "composer/installers": "~1.0"
  },
  "extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
      "server/vendor/{$name}": ["vendor/package"]
    }
  }
}
```

But it's still installing to default directory, it's "project/vendor/", what I want is to install it to "project/server/vendor/"
I save my composer.json in project folder. I know it could be done by placing the composer.json in project/server folder and just do "cd server" and "composer install" or "composer install -d=/server/" in terminal, but I didn't want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

all you need to do is set this directive in the composer.json

ex:

```
"config": {
        "vendor-dir": "libs/vendor"
    },
```